# Update UI with data received by AsyncTask in a service

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an activity that starts and binds a service. 
The service does an AsyncTask with some HttpPost and process the received data to get some variables from the results. 
How can I update the UI in the activity with those data as soon the service get it from the HttpPost? Should I use ResultReceiver or there is a better way?

**Update**:

I think I'll use the **BroadcastReceiver** or the **Observable object**.

Comment: if you are bound, you can send back the data to the activity

Comment: I have to update the interface within the AsyncTask. I don't think I can use the bond, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some possibilites:

Your Service can send a brodcast(sendBroadcast) and your activity just need register a broacastReceiver according your implemented on your service. Something like that:
Your service:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("youAction");    
intent.putExtra("url",uri.toString());
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

On your AndroidManifest of your application:

```
<receiver android:name="MyReceiver" >
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="yourAction" />
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Your Activity:

```
private class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

         String url = arg1.getExtras().getString("url");
         //Here you can update your UI
   }
```

This link can helo you : http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

The second way is register a listener on your service and notify that listener on your service.

In your service:

```
 void onSomethingHappened()
 {
      activityListener.notifyProgressBar();
 }

 void subscribe(YourInterface listener)
 {
      actibityListener =  listener;
 }
 In you activity, after start you service:

 service.subscribe(this);
```

However, to take the better solution you should take into account your service       implementation(type).

This link about [AndroidService](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) can be useful.

However, another imporant point is that your choice **depends of how you implement your async task**. Depends of what you do on each method, preExucute, doInBackground, onProgressUpdate and postExecute.

**You have to keep in mind that you will update your UI from an event that happend outside the AndroidUIThread**, so you will get a problem if you try to update your UI directly. To solve this problem you can use the method [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) of your actitivy ou can use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

Answer (score 0):

Download data in doInBackground(). Show progress dialog in onpreExecute(). Dismiss dialog in onPostExecute(). Update UI with the data in onPostExecute().